# Can't get textarea value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, plupload

I have a submit form for writing a caption in an image. I'm using plupload for this. When file is uploaded it will append a div and inside it is a textarea where you can write your caption of that image. But I always getting an error of Undefined Index when submitting a form. 
This is my code when file was uploaded:

```
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file) {
    var filename = file.id + '.' + file.name.split(".").pop()
    var uploaded_files = $('#uploaded_files').attr('value');
    var appended_files = uploaded_files + file.id + ',';
    $('#uploaded_files').attr('value', appended_files);
    var prev = '<div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:5px;" id="upload-' + file.id + '">' +
            '<div class="col-sm-3">' +
            '<img class="img-thumbnail" width="100%" height="auto"  src="./assets/images/gallery/resorts_gallery/' + filename + '">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-sm-6">' +
            '<textarea name="' + file.id + '_Caption" class="form-control" style="font-size:12px;height:70px" placeholder="Put a caption"></textarea>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-sm-3"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="remove_img(\'' + file.name + '\',\'' + file.id + '\')"><span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></span></a></div>' +
            '</div>';
    $("#prevCap").append(prev);
});
```

In my html:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" id="submit-review" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="uploadphoto">Share your Experiences by uploading Photos</label> <span class="small-text">(optional)</span><br/>  
        <div class="well" id="caption-thumb"> <!-- preview and caption -->
            <div id="prevCap" class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:10px"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="uploaded_files" id="uploaded_files" value="" />
            <hr>
            <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#upload-modal">Add Photos</button>
            <hr id="hr-line" style="display:none">
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-embossed btn-default" id="btnsubmit" name="submit" disabled value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

in my php i do something like this:

```
$last_id = insert_getID("reviews", $fields, $val);
$uploaded_files = $_POST['uploaded_files'];
$uploaded_files = explode(',', $uploaded_files);
$uploaded_files = array_filter($uploaded_files);
foreach ($uploaded_files as $file) {
    $wherefields = array('img_name', 'users_id');
    $upload_value = $file;
    $wherevalues = array($upload_value, $_SESSION['uid']);
    $where_file = where($wherefields, $wherevalues, "", "");
    $caption = $file . "_Caption";
    $file_caption = $_POST['\'' . $caption . '\''];
    $file_field = array('review_id', 'caption');
    $file_value = array($last_id, $file_caption);
    update('gallery', $file_field, $file_value, $where_file);
    echo "<pre>" + $file_caption + "</pre>";
}
```

WHen the files where successfully uploaded, textarea will append inside the div `#prevCap` and that div was also inside the form. I'm getting an error because the form can't get the value of textarea. How can i fix this problem, how can i get textarea value that was appended?

Comment: Shouldn't you replace `$_POST['\''.$caption.'\'']` with `$_POST[$caption]`?

Comment: I think you're overthinking this: `$file_caption = $_POST['\''.$caption.'\''];`. Try `$file_caption = $_POST[$caption];`

Comment: I've already tried those and the same error appeared.

Comment: Hint: Try using `isset` on suspicious occasions where an array is accessed. Put some `echo` statements in between code lines to determine where the error is.

Comment: I've also tried isset and put some echo. same error Undefined Index  and echo a 0 textarea value. I tried to alert it using jquery but it shows the value of textarea. i don't get it why the $_POST can't get the value of textarea when submit a form.

Comment: Have you looked at the request in your browser's developer tools to see what's actually getting sent to the PHP?

Comment: How can i do that? please help me troubleshoot this.

Comment: I prefer Chrome, so that's what I would use. Here's their developer pages on using the Network inspector: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network. You'll be looking for your stuff in the [Request Headers](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#http-headers) of your request to the PHP.